# URL SegmentError: Cannot match any routes in ionic4

Tags: ionic4

I got this error when I click the button to go to the other page. I'm working with Ionic 4.

Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'menu/tabs/tabs/tab-home/registered/outpatient-settings/PPSettingsPath'

I found many topics with this error but didn't find a solution there. I not sure why there is an " outpatient-settings/"

In my HTML

```
<div class="pandora-box" routerLink="PPSettingsPath" [queryParams]="{PsPrnNumber: patientDetails?.prn }">
```

In my ts file.

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
  if (event && event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url) {
     this.PPSettingsPath = event.url + '/pp-settings';
  }
```

I hope someone would help me in this.

Comment: Maybe change to a dynamic variable? `routerLink="{{ PPSettingsPath }}"`. Now the routerlink looks for the string PPSettingsPath

Comment: The link is taking the string of  PPSettingsPath, but it comes out  Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'menu/tabs/tabs/tab-home/registered/outpatient-settings%3FPrnNumber%3D00-000021/pp-settings' when the button is press

Comment: Problem is your queryParams, which are added before the `/pp-settings`. If you look closely to your error output, the first `%3F` is ASCII for `?`. The second `%3D` is ASCII for `=`. I presume the `/pp-settings` must come before the queryparams?